# Write an aggregate query to return the sum of Closed Won opportunities for the current year (Close Date = THIS YEAR) grouped by the account

Tags: apex, soql, query, aggregate

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults
  = [SELECT AVG(Amount)aver FROM Opportunity];
Object avgAmount = groupedResults[0].get('aver');
```

Comment: What is your question? Have you reviewed the documentation on [grouping in SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm)?

Comment: Did you just copy some random code to paste here? The code you posted is completely disconnected from your title. And is there a question?

Comment: sorry by mistake i posted differt code

Comment: [select count(id) from opportunity where iswon= true groupedby account]

Comment: This SOQL is not valid, did you try it in dev console once?

Comment: I don't mean to be disrespectful, but your last couple of questions are written in the style of exam or interview assignments. Providing more context and showing *your* work can help avoid that perception.

Comment: sorry @DavidReed

Answer (score 1):

You can do some tweaks in existing soql and get sum.

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT AccountId, SUM(Amount) sum
                                    FROM Opportunity
                                    WHERE CloseDate = THIS_YEAR AND Stagename = 'Closed Won'
                                    GROUP BY AccountId];
for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
    System.debug('Account ID ' + ar.get('AccountId'));
    System.debug('Sum ' + ar.get('sum'));
}
```

Use `IsClosed` and `IsWon` boolean fields instead of stagename if needed.

Refer [Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) and [Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)